# Widths in EM not acting as I'd expect

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a container that is '32 characters wide' and set default font-size to 1em, then create 2 other styles that allow the font to be changed so that only 24 or 42 characters per lines are possible when the corresponding styles are used (C24 or C42). The font size setting is working ok, but the container is appearing wider than I'd expect. In chrome, in the document inspector, if I change the container to '20em', it's the correct size, but this isn't the behavior I'd expect, is something wrong with my CSS, or what?

my css

```
/*setting this outer container font just in case*/
div.outer 
{
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family : "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}   

div.printContainer 
{
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family : "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    width: 32em;
    border:1px solid #EEEEEE;       
}

div.printContainer div.C42 
{
    font-size : 0.73em;
}

div.printContainer div.C32 
{
    font-size : 1em;        
}

div.printContainer div.C24 
{
    font-size : 1.33em;     
}
```

my Html

```
<div style="" class="outer">
    <div class="printContainer">
        <div class="C24">012345678901234567890123</div>
        <div>01234567890123456789012345678901</div>
        <div class="C42">012345678901234567890123456789012345678901</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I've made a fiddle to demontrate... http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjanoel/bywQp/

As you can see in my html, when I set style to 'C24', I'd like the line to be wide enough for only 24 character, or more like, I'm increasing the font size so that only 24 characters fit.

My problem, if one looks at the fiddle I made, one can see that the 'C' font styles basically make each line of text the correct length, but the outer container is much wider than '32em' (which is my 'default' line width).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`em` is the font **height**, not the width. Since most monospace fonts are rectangular, not square, they are not equivalent.

> **em unit**
>   Equal to the computed value of the ‘font-size’ property of the element on which it is used.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths

You could try the `ch` unit:

> **ch unit**
>   Equal to the advance measure of the "0" (ZERO, U+0030) glyph found in the font used to render it.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ch-unit

… but it is new, and browser support might not be sufficient.

Comment: it's the font height not the font width!!!???!! i'd be surprised if this is true, as all the tutorials say it's a great way to set WIDTH, lol, but then, as I say, not working as I'd expect.

Comment: I quoted, and linked to, the specification. It is relative to the font height.

Comment: It is a common and odd misconception the `em` is the width of “M”. The odd thing is that it is so easy to see that it isn’t, e.g. by constructing an element that is `1em` wide and putting an “M” there.

Comment: em mentions nothing about height in the specification, maybe they should make it clearer, if I hadn't read your answer first I wouldn't have even thought 'this is saying it is the height', and even with your answer in mind, I dont quite see how they are saying it is the height, they only say 'Equal to the computed value of the ‘font-size’ property of the element on which it is used'. So all those tutorials saying use EM for width... it doesn't work for the reasons I'd expect.

Comment: [font-size … This property indicates the desired height of glyphs from the font](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-prop)

Comment: The formulation in the CSS 2.1 spec is a bit vague. It could be misread as saying that the font size equals the height of glyphs. In reality, the height of most glyphs is smaller. The font size is an abstract property, and it is the *reference* height of the font; each glyph is in proportion to this reference height.

Answer (score 1):

To address the practical problem more explicitly (see @Quentin’s answer for an excellent explanation of the principles):

If you want something to be *N* characters wide when a monospace font is used, set its width in to *N* `ch` units and back this up with a preceding setting in `em` units, for browsers that do not support `ch`. The relation between `ch` and `em` depends on the font. For Courier New (as shipped with Windows) it appears to be such that `ch` is about `0.625em`. I found this by some testing. I’m not so sure about the theory; in Courier New, the advance width (ADW) is 1229 units, with 2048 units in `em`, and this would seem to imply a little smaller value, but presumably there is some gutter between characters that explains the difference.

So to set an element 32 characters wide, you would set for it

```
width: 20em;
width: 32ch;
```

Of course, if the actual font is not Courier New, the width may be a different from the desired width on browsers that do not support the `ch` unit. According to [MDN info on units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/length), Chrome does not support `ch`, but support exists at least in Chrome 28beta.